# Boot Camp restarted back to OS X instead of Windows

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I just tried to install BootCamp for Windows 8.1 on my new retina MacBook Pro and it was making the USB stick for like 1 hour then it partitioned the disc and after that, when it should restart to install menu, it automatically restarted back to OS X. So now my disk is split but I can’t run the installation since it has automatically booted into OS X. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

go into system preferences, choose startup disk and select your windows partition, then restart.